# buffered channel not blocking for write when reached its capacity

Tags: go, concurrency

https://play.golang.org/p/5A-dnZVy2aA

```golang
func closeChannel(stream chan int) {
    fmt.Println("closing the channel")
    close(stream)
}

func main() {
    chanOwner := func() <-chan int {
        resultStream := make(chan int, 5)
        go func() {
            defer closeChannel(resultStream)
            for i := 0; i <= 5; i++ {
                resultStream <- i
            }
        }()
        return resultStream
    }
    resultStream := chanOwner()
    for result := range resultStream { //this blocks until the channel is closed
        fmt.Printf("Received: %d\n", result)
    }
    fmt.Println("done receiving")
}
```

Output of program

```
closing the channel
Received: 0
Received: 1
Received: 2
Received: 3
Received: 4
Received: 5
done receiving
```

why is the `closing the channel` statement printed before any `Received` in the above program. since the channel is buffered with a capacity of 5, and we are inserting 6 elements into it, I was expecting it to block at the `resultStream <- i` before a value was read and cleared up space in the buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generator goroutine fills the channel to its capacity and blocks. The receiver for loops receives the first item from the channel, which enables the generator goroutine again. The generator goroutine runs to completion before the receiver for-loop can print the `Received` message, printing the `closing the channel` message. Then the receiver loop receives all remaining messages.

Comment: shouldn't one Received be printed before "closing the channel" since the generator go routine blocks when operating at its max capacity ?

Comment: The generator goroutine can run immediately after the for-loop reads the first message, before printing the `Received` line.